# How do I calculate p values of a linear regression given the covariance matrix and fit coefficients

Tags: c, r, regression, p-value

I have performed a linear regression in C using the GSL library. I've performed the same regression in R. I can access the p values for this regression in R using the "summary" command.

In C, I have the covariance matrix, sum of squared residuals value and fit coefficients. Using these, how do I calculate the p values?

I have attempted this approach using "[Getting p-value for linear regression in C gsl_fit_linear() function from GSL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503733/getting-p-value-for-linear-regression-in-c-gsl-fit-linear-function-from-gsl-li)"

Can anyone confirm it's validity? The results it gives differ for me compared to R.

I have isolated this line of C code as incorrect, but I can't see why:

```
double pv0=t0<0?2*(1-gsl_cdf_tdist_P(-t0,n-2)):2*(1-gsl_cdf_tdist_P(t0,n-2));//This is the p-value of the constant term
```

Results given by R:

Coefficients:

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -700.000    226.569  -3.090  0.05373 . 
x             60.000      6.831   8.783  0.00311 **
```

Results given by C:

```
Coefficients    Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -700.000000  226.568606 -3.089572 -550099700.000000
          x   60.000000    6.831301  8.783101 -4.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting @ben-bolker

Comment: Something certainly looks bogus. Can you print out the values of `t0`, `n`, and `gsl_cdf_tdist_P(abs(t0),n-2)` ? (I think you have `abs` in the standard math library, right?)

Comment: t0=-3.089572, n=5, gsl_cdf_tdist_P(abs(t0),n-2)= 0.0

Comment: From the "Results given by C" it is obvious `gsl_cdf_tdist_P` is returning ridiculous values: by definition, its result must lie between $0$ and $1$ inclusive.  The correct value for $t_0=-3.089572,n-2=3$ is $0.02686583$. The code is a little surprising by not using `gsl_cdf_tdist_Q`, which would be preferable.  (If well-coded, it avoids the huge loss of precision resulting from the subtraction from $1$.) The use of a conditional rather than the absolute value is also a little strange. In other words, `pv0 = 2 * gsl_cdf_tdist_Q(abs(t0), n-2)` would be the natural way to code this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsl_cdf_tdist_P` should expect two `double` arguments and return a `double` between 0 and 1.

Check all your types first.

If it's returning values outside 0-1 when all the types are correct, there's a very serious problem somewhere.

Comment: Yes it was the missing header that screwed the types as C compilers assume functions return ints when they can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was compiling without warnings on and I didn't see that gsl_cdf_tdist_P was being implicitly declared. This led the compiler to think that the function must return an integer. I included the relevant gsl header and got values that match R.